# PHPunit File Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, tdd, phpunit

I'm relatively new to PHPUnit and TDD, and I was wondering how I might test the following code:

```
class File
{
    /**
     * Write data to a given file
     * 
     * @param string $file
     * @param string $content
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function put($path, $content)
    {
        return file_put_contents($path, $content);
    }
}
```

How can I test if the file was created WITHOUT actually creating the file (with PHPUnit obviously).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock the file system for your unit tests by using a virtual file system like [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) with documentation [here](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki)

**EDIT**

An example would be something like:

```
class FileTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var  vfsStreamDirectory
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * set up test environmemt
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->root = vfsStream::setup('exampleDir');
    }

    /**
     * test that the file is created
     */
    public function testFileIsCreated()
    {
        $example = new File();
        $filename = 'hello.txt';
        $content = 'Hello world';
        $this->assertFalse($this->root->hasChild($filename));
        $example->put(vfsStream::url('exampleDir/' . $filename), $content);
        $this->assertTrue($this->root->hasChild($filename));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely take a look. Is it also possible to do mock the file system with Mockery, or by myself. I'm curious how the file system is being mocked.

Comment: vfsStream basically creates a wrapper around the `file://` stream, allowing it to simulate all filesystem functions. As far as I'm aware, it can be used with any test framework (phpunit, simpletest, phpspec, etc), including helpers like mockery

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example of how I would use vfsStream within  the code that I supplied with my question? If its not too much asked.